# A non slangy word for "distractible person"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of starting a 12 step inspired support group, for people struggling with distractions. Basically it would be a group for people with ADHD symptoms, whether they actually have the disorder, or have simply wrecked their attention spans by using the internet too much.

What would be a good name to put before "Anonymous" to convey this scope? A tongue in cheek name like "Scatterbrains Anonymous" or "Spaceshots Anonymous" seems like it might put people off. I'm looking for something that would be to "distractible" as "depressive" the noun is to "depressive" the adjective. I've considered the neologism route, with "Distractives Anonymous", but it seems like a reach to get people identifying with a term that doesn't even exist yet. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I dunno, here's a thought...how about emphasizing the goal of the group instead of focusing on their shortcomings? You can pick a name for the group that is an acronym or something they'd be proud to attend.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about giving names to things.

Comment: Hi Bradd, I was actually hoping to find an existing word that would fit the criteria I described. I included contextual details because they seemed like the most direct way to illustrate what I was looking for. Didn't intend to start a brainstorming jam, though I appreciate the ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Have you thought of **Short Attention Span**? As in *"I'm a member of Short Attention Spans Ano... oh look, something shiny!"*

Answer (score 2):

Consider A.M.A. "[Absent Minds](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absentminded) Anonymous," "Daydreamers Anonymous," and "[Woolgatherers](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/woolgathering) Anonymous."

Answer (score 1):

**Unfocused Anonymous**

> cause to lose concentration or attention. "it might unfocus the jury
>   and distract it"

Answer (score 0):

Over Attenders Anonymous would acknowledge that folks with ADD and ADHD have not so much a deficit in attention as a difficult to manage attentiveness. They are differently attentive and may find that their attention is often somewhere other than where others or particular tasks demand.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in a play on the words '**moider**' or '**Moider Peak**'?  The word ["moider" can mean to perplex or to confuse, and at the time of the survey, the area to the northwest of this peak was obscured by low cloud, and its relationship with other features in the vicinity could not be determined.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moider_Peak)